# JQuery Validation - radio button required for text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

I have two radio buttons and a text input. I want one of the radios required for the text input to be then validated.  I can disable the text input field unless selected, but I think it would be more user intuitive to allow text input first, and only error if they don't also select a radio.

The form is giving me back an error that the radios are required, but I don't want the remote check to kick in unless one of the radio buttons is selected.

So here's what I have...
**JQuery:**

```
jQuery( "#modalform" ).validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: false,
    rules: {
        'register_domain[]': {
            required: true             
        },
        chosen_domain: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4,
            remote: {
                url: "check.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    register_domain: function() {
                        return jQuery('input[name="register_domain[]"]');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        },
    messages: {
        'register_domain[]': {
            required: "Choose one"
        },
        chosen_domain: {
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary"),
            remote: jQuery.validator.format("Invalid domain name: {0}")
        }
    }
});
```

**Form Fields:**

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="register_domain[]" id="own_domain" value="owned"> Own Domain
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="register_domain[]" id="new_domain" value="new"> Register Domain
</label>
<label for="register_domain[]" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
<input type="text" size="50" placeholder="www." id="inputDomain" name="chosen_domain" class="form-control required" required="required">
```

Comment: Main question :What is NOT working ?

Comment: What is not working, is that the remote method activates even though the radio buttons weren't selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"I don't want the remote check to kick in unless one of the radio buttons is selected."*

You can use [the `rules('add')` and `rules('remove')` methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to toggle the `remote` rule within an external `change` handler...

```
$('input[name="register_domain[]"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "owned") {
        $('input[name="chosen_domain"]').rules('remove', 'remote');
    } else {
        $('input[name="chosen_domain"]').rules('add', {
            remote: {
                url: "check.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    register_domain: function() {
                        return jQuery('input[name="register_domain[]"]');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sparky, I'll try this once I'm back to the computer.

Comment: @JamesShaver , he is sparky , :) his code Will work for sure :)